# Dynamically add v-tab-item while maintaining animation order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to dynamically update the items shown in a Vuetify `<v-tabs-items>` group, but the animation is not working properly. When I select a newly added tab, the animation always acts as if that tab were to the right, despite it being to the left in the DOM. How can I correct this, so the order that the tabs appear in the tab bar reflects the direction of movement?

In this example, note that for the original tabs, clicking on a tab further right causes it to be animated in from the right. However, after adding a new tab on the left, clicking on this new  tab causes it to slide in from the right not the left.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-dynamic-v-tabs-items-9egww)

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-card>
      <v-tabs v-model="chosenTab" grow>
        <v-tab v-for="x in xs" :key="x">
          {{ x }}
        </v-tab>
      </v-tabs>
      <v-tabs-items v-model="chosenTab">
        <v-tab-item v-for="x in xs" :key="x">
          <v-card flat>
            <v-card-text>
              {{ x }}
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-tab-item>
      </v-tabs-items>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn @click="xs.unshift('new-tab-' + xs.length)"> Add new tab </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      chosenTab: null,
      xs: ["tab-0", "tab-1", "tab-2"],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `href` prop on `v-tab` and `id` prop on `v-tab-item` - otherwise it will not work. Tabs must have unique string identifiers - relying on the default numeric indexing is error-prone because it (the numeric indexing) depends on the tab's creation order rather than their position in DOM.

Every time a new tab is detected by VTabs - it goes through the `created()` hook in `mixins/groupable/index.js` which in turn calls `register()` method in `VItemGroup.js`. New tabs are always pushed to the internal array with tabs - so their internal order (which is used by the animation) depends on their creation order.

You can not change this behavior unless you patch Vuetify. So in order to overcome it - you must `key` the `v-tab-item` by their index rather than by their ID. Yes, this will cause needless rerendering - but this is the price for working around this "wrong" Vuetify behavior until they fix it.

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-card>
      <v-tabs v-model="chosenTab" grow>
        <v-tab v-for="x in xs" :key="x" :href="'#'+x">
          {{ x }}
        </v-tab>
      </v-tabs>
      <v-tabs-items v-model="chosenTab">
        <v-tab-item v-for="(x,idx) in xs" :key="idx" :id="x">
          <v-card flat>
            <v-card-text>
              {{ x }}
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-tab-item>
      </v-tabs-items>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn @click="xs.unshift('new-tab-' + xs.length)"> Add new tab </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi IVO, sorry I oversimplified my MWE to exclude these properties, they are present in my real code. However, they don’t seem to make any difference to the problem at hand: even when adding href, value and id, the animation direction does not change.

Comment: Well, you should use the array index as `key` for `v-tab` and `v-tab-item` - not the tab name/id as you did in your Sandbox.

Comment: This does not maintain the content: any data stored in the elements in the tabs aren’t maintained within each tab. Key is meant to maintain a reference to the same element, to minimise rerendering, but this causes each component to receive the props of the previous, so `data` is not maintained within each tab

Comment: Your issue is caused because `v-tabs-items` maintains internal array with the tabs - and this array is ordered by the creation time of each tab so that each new tab is pushed at the back of this array. You can not change this behavior (unless you patch Vuetify) - so in order to overcome it, you should `key` the tabs by their index in **your** array. Yes, it will cause needless rerendering - but otherwise you can not solve the issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks Ivo. If you add that to the answer I’ll mark it as accepted